# WebClient.UploadFile failed with "The request was aborted: The request was canceled."

Tags: web-applications

I am trying to upload a file to a HTTP URL with [WebClient.UploadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esst63h0.aspx). For small file such as 1M, 2M, the uploading is successful. But for a big file such as 12M, I got this exception:

```
The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
```

Has anyone met this problem before and could you share the solution?

### Some info:

- The server is using ASP.NET 3.5.
- The HTTP method I used in uploading is "PUT".

Comment: Is the receiving server configured to accept requests that large? For example, the default in most ASP.NET Websites is 4 MB. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxrequestlength.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution referred to in smwikipedia's answer. I've added the ability to disable write stream buffering, which can help with out of memory exceptions.

```
public class ExtendedWebClient : WebClient
{
    public int Timeout { get; set; }
    public new bool AllowWriteStreamBuffering { get; set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request != null)
        {
            request.Timeout = Timeout;
            var httpRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
            if (httpRequest != null)
            {
                httpRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = AllowWriteStreamBuffering;
            }
        }
        return request;
    }

    public ExtendedWebClient()
    {
        Timeout = 100000; // the standard HTTP Request Timeout default
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var webClient = new ExtendedWebClient();
webClient.Timeout = Timeout.Infinite;
webClient.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
webClient.UploadFile(url, filePath);
```

Comment: Thanks for improving it. I change to mark yours as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it according to here: 
[Extend the timeout value of WebClient](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoftwareDoneRight/archive/2010/09/14/supporting-request-timeout-with-a-webclient.aspx)

And by the way in case of OutOfMemory exception due the buffering of WebClient:
[Are you getting OutOfMemoryExceptions when uploading large files?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johan/archive/2006/11/15/are-you-getting-outofmemoryexceptions-when-uploading-large-files.aspx)